# Strange Mongoosejs model behaviour with pre-hooks on undefined and enums being ignored

Tags: node.js, validation, enums, mongoose

I have a model that is acting very strangely in two respects.

1) pre-hooks, issues with one specific field.

My schema has in its root a params object with fields inside. If I place the following field inside the params object:

```
        roles:[{
        "type": String,
        "enum": ['user', 'artist', 'promoter', 'admin']
    }],
```

I get this result:

```
 if(this.params.roles.length == 0){
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

However if I instead use this structure (which is the same structure with a different name and enum):

```
        permissions:[{
            "type": String,
            "enum": ["Delete","Show","Create","Update"]
        }],
```

then the insert is successful.

Further to this if I move the roles array into the root of the model the insert is also successful.

This is what the pre hook looks like (straight replacement of `permissions` for `roles` to go from success to failure)

```
userSchema.pre("save", function(next){
    if(this.params.permissions.length == 0){

        this.params.permissions.push("luser")
    }
    next()
});
```

2) enums: ignored

For permissions I can enter PELETE into the field and for roles i can enter luser successfully.

Both of these behaviours seem buggy to me as any combination of the array structure in point 1 works except for 'roles' (which is mentioned no where else in the application, the intention was for the hook to set that parameter).

Anyone have any insight, I'm guessing the issues are related as my enums work in singular String fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was buggy, by it i mean my code and understanding:

Problem 1) Was my incoming validation. I was overwriting the empty array with undefined.

Problem 2) the enum (and i suspect other validation) is ignored when you perform an action in the pre save hook.